Python-Docx Table Row Border limit?
I'm having an issue with Table Row borders. All seems to be working great up to rows 250-260 in all tables. Although my script indicates the task is getting done, the output shows no borders after said rows. Is there a strange upper limit or something? Data will write to the table as it should, cell merging will happen as it should, just the borders will stop being drawn.
Running python-docx v1.1.2 in python 3.9.2.
Just so it's here, here is my function that I'm calling, which again is function all the way up to these rows:
def set_whole_row_border(table, part_row):
    tbl = table._tbl
    rows = tbl.getchildren()
    for this_row in rows:
        if isinstance(this_row, CT_Row):
            cells = this_row.getchildren()
            if this_row.tr_idx is part_row:
                for cell in cells:
                    tcPr = cell.tcPr
                    tcBorders = OxmlElement('w:tcBorders')

                    top = OxmlElement('w:top')
                    top.set(qn('w:val'), 'single')
                    top.set(qn('w:sz'), '12')
                    top.set(qn('w:space'), '0')
                    top.set(qn('w:color'), '#000000')
                    tcBorders.append(top)

                    bottom = OxmlElement('w:bottom')
                    bottom.set(qn('w:val'), 'single')
                    bottom.set(qn('w:sz'), '4')
                    bottom.set(qn('w:space'), '0')
                    bottom.set(qn('w:color'), '#000000')
                    tcBorders.append(bottom)

                    tcPr.append(tcBorders)

    print('border done for row', part_row)


See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is.
So instead if this_row.tr_idx is part_row: do if this_row.tr_idx == part_row: and it should work.

I was also able to get around this by pulling this function and putting the snippet in the main function. Super strange that it would just stop executing in the loop. Not ideal, so I will try your solution as well, Axel. Thank you
